# In C# why does helpRequested() event of parent Form get called instead of child Form?

Tags: c#

**Scenario:**
-I have a ParentForm of which HelpRequest event is Subscribed.
-On ParentForm Button Click ChildForm gets opened.
-HelpRequest event is not subscribed for childForm.

**Actually Result**
-But still when I am in my childForm, and I press 'F1' HelpRequest event of ParentForm gets triggered.

**Expected Result**
-I expected to happen nothing.

Why does this happen..?

Comment: Which form has focus? And how do you open child form (and is this winforms/wpf)

Comment: I suspect that this is some form of event bubbling - if the control doesn't handle this event, pass it up to the parent to see if it wants to handle it (and so on up the parent/child relationships until you reach the top) - but I can't point to any specific documentation on this.

Comment: Please tag your question with WinForms or WPF or whatever.

Comment: the focus is on Child form..On parent form click button I create an object of Child form and just show it

Comment: Just take an example of Form1 as a parent and Form2 as child..

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of event bubbling, but I can't see it clearly documented anywhere.

However, it's quite obvious if you look at the implementation of [`Control.OnHelpRequested`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/a.html#d2b4167e36ee4393):

```
HelpEventHandler handler = (HelpEventHandler)Events[EventHelpRequested];
if (handler != null) {
    handler(this,hevent);
    // VSWhidbey 95281: Set this to true so that multiple events aren't raised...
    hevent.Handled = true;
}

if (!hevent.Handled) {
    if (ParentInternal != null) {
        ParentInternal.OnHelpRequested(hevent);
    }
}
```

That is, if you don't define a handler within a particular control, then it's explicitly passed up to the parent control.

This makes a great deal of sense - a lot of things are `Control`s and you don't necessarily want to wire up help for each of them individually - so if you have a parent form with a child form and you've only written one help page that covers all usage of the parent and the child, just install the help handler in the parent form.

Conversely, if you do have a help page that just addresses how the `OK` button works, then you'd add a help handler into the `OK` button's `HelpRequested`.

And if you want to *suppress* this event bubbling up to the parent, just make sure you've installed a `HelpRequested` handler that doesn't do anything